# AUTO_KEY not getting populated when a new SQL record inserted?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The table in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 looks like this...

[image]

I am inserting a new record from a trigger on another table as follows...

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FMQP] (PFIID,TITLE,DUEDATE,SUMMARY,STATUSABRV,USELOC,OPENED,CLOSED,CANDC,SNDNWEMAIL,SENDNEWNOW,SITECODE,BLDGCODE,FLOORCODE,BLDG,FLOOR,LOCATION)
VALUES (@proposedPFIID,@title,@DueDate,@summary,'Open PFI',@item,@opened,0,0,1,0,@SiteCode,@BldgCode,@floorCode,@bldg,@floor,@Location)
```

It gets inserted with AUTO_KEY set to 0. If I try to add another record the insert fails , as expected, because AUTO_KEY is again set to 0 and AUTO_KEY is unique.

I have this same code running in a duplicate of this site running SQL Server 2008 R2 and it is working fine there. What could be different in this site, this trigger, or this table that could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Have you defined `auto_key` to be an `identity`?

Comment: Thank you! You got me looking me in the right direction. The problem was the "Default value or binding".  I have to create tables in this database from within a 3rd party app and the AUTO_KEY column gets created automatically. For some reason unlike every other table in this database, this table on this site had (0) entered for that property instead of ([dbo][getautokey]()). Popped that function in there where it belonged and all is good. Post an asnwer and I will give you credit. Otherwise I will answer my own question when the system allows me to.